# In lotus notes, "Delivery Failure Report" are to be moved to another folder, rule doesn't work since the report is not in the memo form

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In lotus notes, "Delivery Failure Report" are to be moved to another folder, rule doesn't work since the report is not in the memo form. These are auto generated mails so we can not do any edits while sending them, but can we move the failure reports to another folder/trash. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write an agent to do this. Normally, you would have a choice between triggering the agent immediately before, or shortly after the message is delivered, but in this case you will have to trigger it after delivery. That's because you can't move it out of the inbox and into another folder before it's even in the inbox. You can find documentation on writing agents [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTWP_8.5.3/com.ibm.notes85.client.doc/agt_automate_task_using_agent_c.html).